# golang aws CreateChangeSet validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cloudformation

Attempting to update a single key/value of a parameter in an existing Cloudformation template.

...

```
svc := cloudformation.New(AWSSession)

// Add parameters. Used in AWS CreateStack/UpdateStack call
var params []*cloudformation.Parameter
for key, val := range cfnparamsOverrides {
    log.Printf("Adding parameter key-> %v value-> %v", key, val)
    param := &cloudformation.Parameter{}
    param.ParameterKey = aws.String(key)
    param.ParameterValue = aws.String(val)
    params = append(params, param)
}

CreateChangeSetInput := &cloudformation.CreateChangeSetInput{
    StackName:     aws.String(stackARN),      // required field.
    ChangeSetName: aws.String(ChangeSetName), // must be a unique value
    ChangeSetType: aws.String("UPDATE"),
    // TemplateBody:  aws.String(templateBody),
    UsePreviousTemplate: aws.Bool(true),
    Parameters:          params}

// Issue AWS CreateChangeSet API call
log.Println("Issuing AWS CreateChangeSet() API call")
_, errCreateChangeSet := svc.CreateChangeSet(CreateChangeSetInput)
if errCreateChangeSet != nil {
    return false, fmt.Errorf("Got error on CreateChangeSet: %v", errCreateChangeSet.Error())
}
```

only 1 value is being set, but cloudformation template validation throws the following:
ValidationError: Parameters: [Key1, Key2, Key3, ...] must have values

It seems to be requiring key/value for all the cloudformation paramters existing in the template.  Is there a way to only provide the new/existing key/value pair I need updated?

Within the golang aws documentation I discovered the *cloudformation.Parameter struct has a UsePreviousValue for each value. However I don't see the use of this other than to avoid modifying the existing value, it still requires I provide the same paramaters keys in the deployed cfn template.

Am I missing something?  It seems like a relatively straight forward approach to update an existing value in a deployed environment.

Wondering how others are going about this.  Should I be querying the existing environment to read in all the parameters key/values, modify the 1 I need, and then submit changeset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `UsePreviousValue` is the only way you can do this.

The same behavior is for **AWS CLI** where `create-change-set` or `update-stack` will require you to list all the parameters again and set the `UsePreviousValue="true"` for each of them.

If you want to avoid doing this all the time, you could create a **wrapper** around your `CreateChangeSet` which would automatically populate the parameters.

This limitation origins directly from the [CloudFormation REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateChangeSet.html). The [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateChangeSet.html#API_CreateChangeSet_Examples) provided for the API, also explicitly lists all the parameters and uses `UsePreviousValue` to indicate a re-use of the value:

```
https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
 ?Action=CreateChangeSet
 &ChangeSetName=SampleChangeSet
 &Parameters.member.1.ParameterKey=KeyName
 &Parameters.member.1.UsePreviousValue=true
 &Parameters.member.2.ParameterKey=Purpose
 &Parameters.member.2.ParameterValue=production
 &StackName=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/SampleStack/1a2345b6-0000-00a0-a123-00abc0abc000
 &UsePreviousTemplate=true
 &Version=2010-05-15
 &X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
 &X-Amz-Credential=[Access key ID and scope]
 &X-Amz-Date=20160316T233349Z
 &X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type;host
 &X-Amz-Signature=[Signature]
```

Comment: hey!  thank you for explaining the history. I'm doing the refactor you suggested and first making a call to fetch the existing properties using svc.GetTemplateSummary(). The field names for the "value" are non-conforming so I'm not sure if this is the correct api call to fetch existing properties